# Angular : ng test gives 404 error for api

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular8

I am running `ng test` for unit test on Angular 8.2. I started it with LoginComponent and I am getting 404 error on api load as below.

[image]

I tried adding `*.js` files in karma.config.ts file pattern as below.

[image]

Is there anything I am missing? I am new for writing the unit test for an application.

Comment: Why are your unit tests making real requests?

Comment: @jonrsharpe So I have to create mockAPIs?

Comment: Your components are tested against mock services, your services are tested like https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests

Comment: Okay thanks @jonrsharpe.